# Elasticsearch use filter fo filter out unwanted keywords

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Now I am having some data in the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['foo','some text',1, 13],['foo','Another text',2, 4],['foo','Third text',3, 10],['bar','Text1',2, 25], ['bar','Long text',1, 17],['num','short text',3, 0],['num','fifth text',3, 8]], index = range(1,8), columns = ['category','text','label', 'count'])
```

I've put the documents into an es index and try to searh with the condition of getting "count" that is greater than 0 and less than 10, and "category" that is not "foo".

I tried to use the "none" clause in "filter" clause of a boolean query, but it gives the error of "no query registered for [none]".

```
text: "text"
data = json.dumps({
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
                {
                    "match":{
                        "text":text
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "count": {
                            "from": 0,
                            "to": 10
                    }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "none": {
                        "term": {
                            "category.keyword": "foo"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
            
        }
    }
})
```

So I am now using the "must_not" clause as below:

```
text: "text"
data = json.dumps({
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
                {
                    "match":{
                        "text":text
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "count": {
                            "from": 0,
                            "to": 10
                    }
                }
                }
            ]
            ,
            "must_not":[
                {
                    "term": {
                        "category.keyword": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Is there a way to use "none" in the "filter" clause and to make the query work more efficiently? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), scoring is ignored for the `must_not` clause, so there will be no impact on the performance of the query (used above), even if `must_not` clause is included outside the filter clause.

> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses
> are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a
> score of 0 for all documents is returned.

And apart from this, there is no `none` query, instead, there is only [Match None query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/query-dsl-match-all-query.html#query-dsl-match-none-query), which matches no documents.

Comment: Thank you! So I suppose "must_not" is the correct way to do so. May I know what is the usage of "match_none" query if it matches no documents？

Comment: And to specify, I found the "none" clause in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/filters.html  Seems that the "filter" clause is different from the one in the boolean query I guess?

Comment: @kentoto to know more about the use case of `match_none` you can refer to this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65936510/10348758. And the `none` clause which you are referring to is from Elastic App Search documentation, filter clause used there is different from the `filter` boolean clause in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you so much for the generous help and informative explanation!